# MS Graph send Item type attachment not working

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

```
I'm using Microsoft graph API's but not sure how to send inline attachments ( pictures pasted in email body)
I've tried with this -

    const attachment =     {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
      "name": "img1.jpg",
      "isInline": true,
      "contentBytes": base64.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, "")
    }

    const result = await client.api(`/users/${originEmail}/messages/${emailId}/attachments`).post(attachment)

then I'm updating base64 string with `cid:${result.id}` in email body

but the email which I'm receiving does not show the pictures in email and the attachment can visible as file type attachment

Also try with below code => 
 {
  message: {
    body: {
      contentType: 'html',
      content: "<p class="ql-align-center"><strong style="color: rgb(23, 23, 23);">Azure App Registration</strong><span style="color: rgb(23, 23, 23);">&nbsp;</span></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 1:-&nbsp;</strong> Create app registration in azure portal&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img src="cid:content0">&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 2:-</strong> Add secret credentials&nbsp;</p><p><img src="cid:content1">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 3:- </strong>Remove all default permissions&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp; <img src="cid:content2">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 4:-</strong>&nbsp; Add application permission&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p><img src="cid:content3">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 5:- </strong>Add email related permission and account level permission&nbsp;</p><p><strong>&nbsp; </strong><img src="cid:content4">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Step 6:-&nbsp; </strong>Required admin consent access to approve the added permissions&nbsp;</p><p>Click on Grant admin consent<strong>&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>&nbsp<img src="cid:content5">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"
    },
    toRecipients: [ [Object] ],
    ccRecipients: [ [Object] ],
    bccRecipients: [ [Object] ],
    hasAttachments: true,
    subject: 'test',
    attachments: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}

where object is 

    const obj ={
               "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
               "contentType":"image/png",
               "contentBytes": newString.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, ""),
               "contentId":`content${i}`,
               "isInline": true,
                "name": `image${i}.jpg
    }
```

In obj declaring the fileType attachment as well as Inline flag
but still not getting images in email. if anyone knows this then help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The contentId should match what you set in the Body (not the Id of the attachment eg `cid:${result.id}` wouldn't be valid)  of the Message and should be set when you create the attachment eg

```html
{
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "The new cafeteria is open. <img id='1' src='cid:blah1'>"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "balyh@d.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "name": "img1.png",
            "isInline": true,
            "contentId": "blah1",
            "contentBytes": "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"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your later example you setting the file name to be jpg but the contenttype to be png and you shouldn't be setting hasAttachments: true let the store handle that. If you want to debug what happening i would suggest a Mapi editor like Outlook Spy or MFCMapi you can then look at what properties are being set on the attachment when you create a draft.

Comment: Hi Glen ,
I tried as per your suggestion but still it's not working. I changed the image extenstion from jpg to png and also changed the contentId and same contentId sending in attachments array but no success.

Comment: If you check the attachments using a Mapi editor what do you see in the properties.  You need to look at the traces of what your actually sending as the JSON request (fiddler is good for this on windows machines) it sounds like it maybe not what your expecting. Maybe also try to do some testing by just sending one image to start with and then up the complexity of what your sending.